# Value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bn}}{n^2+z^{2}}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series, potential-theory

I wonder if any of you knows how to find the value
of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bn}}{n^2+z^{2}}.$$

This function shows up while solving a magnetostatic problem
with complex-valued scalar potential.

Greetings

Oscar

Comment: Oh, c'mon @IgorSikora, your *you should show your approach* is offensive to every real mathematician, from children to the most advanced ones. It's highly wrong that this attitude prevails in mathematical education, and extra frustratingly wrong in the case of *Math Stack Exchange*.

Comment: Ok, given the answer it seems I was wrong. Apologies, I am retrieving my previous comment.

Comment: @IgorSikora, it's not about the research level of the *OP Question* but about the wide-spread patronizing/condescending treatment of the students of mathematics -- after all, every mathematician is a student. Mathematics is beautiful but it is surrounded by ugliness (hm, *poetic justice* :) ).

Comment: Please clarify by what you mean by "limiting value". If you mean a "limit", please indicate which variable tends to where.

Comment: @GHfromMO --- the OP wrote "convergence value", I changed that into "limiting value", but I presume that simply "value" is more accurate (and I have changed it accordingly)

Answer (score 4):

The series has no expression in terms of elementary functions, but it does represent a special function (either the [incomplete beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) $B$ or the [Lerch transcendent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html) $\Phi$):
$$F(b,z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-bn}}{n^2+z^2}=-\frac{1}{z}\,{\rm Im}\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-bn}}{n+iz}$$
$$\qquad=-\frac{1}{z}{\rm Im}\,e^{-b} \Phi (e^{-b},1,i z+1)=-\frac{1}{z}{\rm Im}\,e^{ibz}B_{e^{-b}}(i z+1,0).$$
(I'm assuming real $z$ and $b\geq 0$.) Two limits are:
$$F(b,0)=\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-b}\right),$$
a polylog, while
$$F(0,z)=\frac{\pi  z \coth (\pi  z)-1}{2 z^2}.$$